# As IPC 497 is struck down - can any married person now file a divorce based on the fundamental 'right to choose'?

Tags: india, divorce, legal-research, indian-penal-code

Supreme Court of India has [struck down](https://qz.com/india/1404196/adultery-no-longer-crime-in-india-rules-supreme-court/#:%7E:text=Extramarital%20sex%20is%20not%20a%20criminal%20offence%20in,offence%20still%20remains%20a%20valid%20ground%20for%20divorce.) IPC section 497:

> A five-judge bench of the court ruled that section 497 of the Indian Penal Code violates
> women’s right to equality and treats them like the property of their
> husbands. “It’s time to say that (a) husband is not the master of
> (his) wife,” Chief Justice of India, Dipak Misra read out from the judgement.

- So, now, can any married person get a divorce without any arguments and/or accusing their partners, based on
  the 'right to choose' as a fundamental right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Different civil codes provide methods for divorce, but in all of them, they have outlined clear "[grounds for divorce](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/readersblog/lawpedia/grounds-for-divorce-in-india-35652/)". One must provide one of these as a reason for divorce.

While adultery is no longer a crime, it is still a ground for divorce.